# ¿Por qué no recibo los datos del formulario en mi componente?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Tengo este formulario en AngularJS:

```
<form #refForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addUser(refForm)">

  <div class="form-group d-flex ">
    <div class="w-50">
      <label for="full_name_input">Full Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="full_name" id="full_name_input" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name">
    </div>
    <div class="w-50">
      <label for="occupation_input">Occupation</label>
      <input type="text" name="occupation" id="occupation_input" class="form-control" placeholder="Occupation">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group d-flex flex-column">
    <div>
      <label for="join_date_input">Join Date</label>
      <input type="text" name="join_date" id="join_date_input" class="form-control" placeholder="Join Date">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group mt-3">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-end" [mat-dialog-close] value="Close">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success float-end" value="Create">

  </div>

</form>
```

y el metodo del controlador es:

```
 addUser = (f: NgForm) =>
  {
    console.log(f.form.value);
  };
```

cuando hago el console.log(f.form.value) recibo unicamente los timestamp, __v, y _id

Sabéis porqué qué ocurre esto? Gracias de antemano por la ayuda

Comment: @ivanao ¿Estás seguro que OP utiliza Angular? En su pregunta claramente especifica que está utilizando AngularJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te hace falta agregar el atributo/selector [`ngModel`](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) a los campos de formulario. Por ejemplo, con `full_name`:

```html
<input type="text" name="full_name" ngModel id="full_name_input" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name">
```